# VB Macro inserts around ' ' my formula, please assist

Tags: vba, excel

So I created a Macro on a workbook that works 100% perfectly. The data in the file changes on a monthly basis and it is saved as a different file each period. So I made a macro in one workbook and then copied it into other "variants" of this workbook. All parts of the macro execute perfectly except for the "sumif" formula (worked perfectly in the original workbook I made the macro in. Please see below example of VB that executes perfectly in the first file )

```
Range("C5").Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = _
        "=SUMIF(Table2[Sales Reference],'Appendix - Reconcile Work'!RC[-1],Table2[Remaining to be Recognised (converted)])"
```

the formula it creates in the 1st workbook is exactly the same as below.

```
=SUMIF(Table2[Sales Reference],'Appendix - Reconcile Work'!B5,Table2[Remaining to be Recognised (converted)])
```

When I paste this into a different variant workbook (all parameters and specifics are the same as the first file, the full macro runs and completes) but on the 2nd workbook the formula it creates is the below

```
=SUMIF(Table2[Sales Reference],'Appendix - Reconcile Work'!'B5',Table2[Remaining to be Recognised (converted)])
```

-The difference is the B5 it adds ' ' around the B5. All cells match up perfectly across all workbooks.

All help is appreciated

Thanks

Comment: have you tried not using R1C1 notation?

Comment: A workaround could be to use a named range instead of B5